# How do you work out a variable when given the limit to infinity of a function?

Tags: limits

So the velocity function is defined as $v(t) = Ce^{kt} + \frac{9.8}{k}$. It is given that when t = 0, velocity = 0. This leads me to this relationship between C and k:
$0 = C + \frac{9.8}{k}$

Now, if the limit to infinity of the velocity function is -35

$\lim_{t \to \infty} v(t) = -35$ How would I find what C and k are?
What I have tried is as follows:

$ \lim_{t \to \infty} Ce^{kt} + \frac{9.8}{k} = -35$

Substituting the fraction by the above relationship between C and k gives:

$ \lim_{t \to \infty} Ce^{kt} - C = -35$

But now...

$ \lim_{t \to \infty} C(e^{kt} - 1) = -35$

Dividing by $e^{kt} $ gives 0 multiplied by C

$ \lim_{t \to \infty} C(e^{kt} - 1) = -35$

$ \lim_{t \to \infty} C(1 - \frac{1}{e^{kt}}) = -35$

$ \lim_{t \to \infty} C(1 - 0) = -35$

$ \lim_{t \to \infty} C = -35$

However, upon subsequently working out k as 0.28 graphing this, this is wrong.The signs should be switched around where C = 35 and k = -0.28. Is anyone able to tell me how I went wrong? Moreover, is this THE best way to evaluate limits to infinity in this way.

Thanks!

Comment: All your calculations, particularly the evaluation of the limit in the second-to-last equation, seem to assume that $k$ is positive. But if you look at the original formula for $v(t)$, the fact that its limit as $t\to\infty$ exists actually tells us that $k$ must be negative....

Comment: The function $v(t)$ converges, if $Ce^{kt}$ converges. This is the case if $k$ is negative. Or to put it in another way. We substitute $k$ by $-k$ and obtain  $Ce^{-kt}+\frac{9.8}{-k}$. It converges, if $k$ is positive.

$$\lim_{t\to \infty}v(t)=\lim_{t\to \infty} Ce^{-kt}+\frac{9.8}{-k}=\lim_{t\to \infty} Ce^{-kt}-\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{9.8}{k}=-\frac{9.8}{k}$$

This is equal to $-35$. Therefore the equation is $-\frac{9.8}{k}=-35$